# python csv reader + special characters

Tags: python, csv

I am writing script to read a csv file and write the data in a graph using the pygraphml.

Issue is that the file first column has some data like this and I am not able to read them.

Master Muppet ™
joèl b
Kýrie, eléison

This is my python script

```
import csv
import sys
from pygraphml import Graph
from pygraphml import GraphMLParser

#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")

data = []  # networkd data to write
g = Graph() # graph for networks

#Open File and retrive the target rows
with open(r"C:\Users\csvlabuser\Downloads\test.csv","r") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    unread_count = 2
    completed_list = []

    try:
        for rows in reader:
            if "tweeter_id" == rows[2]:  # skip and check the header
                print("tweeter_id column found")
                continue
            #if rows[2] not in completed_list:                    
            n = g.add_node(rows[2].encode("utf8"))
            completed_list.append(rows[2])
            n['username'] = rows[0].encode("utf8")
            n['userid'] = rows[1]
            if rows[3] != "NULL":   # edges exist only when there is retweets id
                g.add_edge_by_label(rows[2], rows[3])


            print unread_count
            unread_count +=1

    except:
        pass

fp.close()
print unread_count

g.show()
# Write the graph into graphml file format
parser = GraphMLParser()
parser.write(g, "myGraph.graphml")
```

Kindly let me know where is the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data is like this 
Master Muppet ™ 
joèl b 
Kýrie, eléison

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I doubt he's getting any errors, thanks to the bare `except` with a `pass` for a body... It would help to know if this is Python 2 or Python 3 though; Python 3's native support for Unicode is much better and more seamless, in Python 2, you're going to have a harder time. In addition, we (and Python) need to know the encoding of the file being read; if the file is `utf-8`, and you read as `latin-1`, or `utf-16`, or vice-versa, you won't interpret the file correctly.

Comment: The error it stops reading when a specific row with such data appers and stop appending it and execute the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 2 `csv` module cannot handle `unicode` input or input containing `NUL` bytes (see the note at the top of the [module page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)). Since you're using `print` as a keyword rather than a function, I'm guessing you're using Python 2. To use `csv` with Unicode in Python 2, you must convert to `UTF-8` encoding.

The [`csv` module's Examples section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) contains definitions for wrappers (`UTF8Recoder`, `UnicodeReader`, `UnicodeWriter`) that allow you to parse inputs in arbitrary encodings, seamlessly fixing up encodings so `csv` can process the inputs, then decoding back to Python `unicode` objects (that represent the text as "pure" Unicode text, not a specific byte encoding).